# Linux AHCI-драйвер с модифицированными операциями ввода/вывода

Tags: linux, c, драйвер

Я хочу изменить в [существующем примере AHCI-драйвера](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/ata/ahci.c) из репозитория Linux операции ввода/вывода и установить этот драйвер на определенный SATA-диск. В частности я хочу изменить операции ввода/вывода так, чтобы части данных читались и записывались через по-битную операцию `xor` с ключом из `shared memory`, что вполне подходит для моего home-made эксперимента. Я много гуглил и смотрел примеры с исходниками, но вконце-концов только запутался.

Можете ли вы подсказать какой пример или файл взять за основу и какие функции для чтения и записи искать, в каком направлении работать?

Comment: я бы через mapper такую операцию делал. ахчи немного не то что для таких операций.